# Setting number of characters for IdeaVIM indentation (<< and >>)

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, ideavim

(Can someone with more karma please create an "ideavim" tag?)

Right now, indenting is always 4, I'm looking for the equivalent of vim's shiftwidth variable.

It seems to honour the IntelliJ preference for indentation in CoffeeScript, but the same is not happening with SASS. It's always 4 characters, even though the preference is set to 2.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem?

Comment: No but didn't look any futher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If identation works properly for SASS when IdeaVim plug-in is not used, please file a bug to the [plug-in tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/VIM). Otherwise it's not plug-in related issue and should be fixed in IDEA itself, [submit a bug here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug for shiftwidth having no effect:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1416

Be sure to upvote the bug report to show interest and speed a fix.

A workaround is to set tab behavior per Language via Preferences.  For example, the path for Javascript is:

Preferences >> Editor >> Code Style >> Javascript